# jQuery Mobile 1.4 Page Navigation

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need to use jQuery Mobile to build an app and I'm stuck at page navigation. I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.4. And the documentation doesn't help me very much. I have a few questions. Any help would be appreciated. Also please point out if I misunderstood anything.

1. I understood that $.mobile.navigate is the recommended method to change between pages in jQuery Mobile 1.4. Hoe can I use it to send data from one page to another?
2. What is the need for pagecontainer widget's load method? The change method itself seems to  load an external page.
3. When I use the pagecontainer widget's change method to load an external page, it loads the page into the DOM and changes to it as expected. But, when I go back, the external page is removed from the DOM. Is there anyway to load an external page only once and let it persist in the DOM as long as the app is running?

Comment: Ok, I got the answer for number 3. I'll have to set DOM Cache option to true on the pages which I want to persist in DOM even after navigation.